# Return a value from AngularJS API service to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, service, factory

If I have a service that looks like this:

```
app.factory('User', function($http, User) {
    var User = function(data) {
        angular.extend(this, data);
    };
    User.prototype.create = function() {
        var user = this;

        return $http.post(api, user.getProperties()).success(function(response) {
            user.uid = response.data.uid;
        }).error(function(response) {

        });
    };

    User.get = function(id) {
        return $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
            return new User(response.data);
        });
    };

    return User;
});
```

How do I, in a controller, get the `User` that was created in the `get()` function?

Currently what I have is:

```
app.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope, User) {
    $scope.user = null;

    User.get($routeParams.rid).success(function(u) {
        $scope.user = new User(u.data);
    });
});
```

The issue is that the `UserCtrl` is getting the api response, not the value returned from the `success()` in the factory. I'd prefer to be making the new user in the factory, as opposed to passing the api response to the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit: May 5th 2015**

I learnt about the [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) while trying to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043495/q-defer-not-working-with-angular-service/).

So we can avoid using `$q.defer()` and use the following code to achieve the same result.

*Service*

```
User.get = function(id) {
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        return new User(response.data);
    });
};
```

*Controller*

```
User.get($routeParams.rid).then(function(u) {
    $scope.user = u;
});
```

**Original Answer below:**

I think what you are looking for is the `$q` service which allows you to do some post processing on the response from the asynchronous `$http` service and then return it to the controller as a promise. Check out the documentation here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

So inject the `$q` service in your factory and change your `User.get` function like below.

```
User.get = function(id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(new User(response.data));
    }).error(function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

And then in your controller you can do

```
User.get($routeParams.rid).then(function(u) {
    $scope.user = u;
}, function(error) {
    //log error
});
```

Comment: I agree that this is a cleaner method.

Answer (score 0):

I think your returns are a bit messed up. Personally I would have written it something like this

```
app.factory('User', function ($http) {

    var user = {
        new: function (data) {
            return $http.post(api, data);
        },
        get: function (id) {
            $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
                return user.new(response.data);
            });
        }
    };

    return user;

});
```

Then from inside your controller..

```
app.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope, User) {
    $scope.user = null;

    User.get($routeParams.rid).success(function(u) {
        $scope.user = u.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I did above. It doesn't work. What happens is that the data returned from the promise is what is passed to the `UserCtrl`

Comment: I've just realised what you've done, by using `new User` you're creating an instance of that factory and returning it. Unless you have another factory called User. If you do can you put up some more code?

Comment: I realized I made a typo above. `app.factory('User')` returns `User`. I could put more code up, but it's the same as above. Just more functions. Some are `.prototype`, others, like `get`, aren't.

Comment: I assumed that was a typo :) my point is do you have a function that creates a user? maybe something like `User.prototype.create`...?

Comment: Added example of `User.prototype.create`.

Comment: Updated my answer with a cleaner way to write your service, not sure if this solves your particular issue but it might help! Best of luck!

Comment: The problem with what you have above is that you can't do `User.get().success()` in `UserCtrl` if you didn't return `$http`, the actual promise, in `User.get()`. I think I managed to figure it out though, and it's based on the difference between `success()` and `then()` with promises. If both the factory and controller used `then()`, it seems to work.

Comment: Using the $q service is a much cleaner way of writing it and helps you easily understand what you are returning from the factory. Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, when i had 'response.data' passed to def.resolve, from controller it throws as undefined. So passed the response directly and it worked.

```
var def = $q.defer();
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/services')
      .success(function (response) {
          ***def.resolve(response);***              
      })
      .error(function (error) {              
          def.reject(error);
      });
      return def.promise;
```